# ERROR: Component interaction/ListenChange not available with base

Tags: noflo, flow-based-programming

I wanted to run a **NoFlo** application. I created a noflo component in json fomat and then I tried to run it with the following command:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs --graph graphs/Number_game.json.
```

I got the following error:

> NoFlo runtime is now listening at ws://192.168.43.64:3569 Browsers
> will reject connections from HTTPS pages to unsecured WebSockets You
> can use insecure version of the IDE, or enable secure WebSockets with
> --tls-key and --tls-cert options Live IDE URL: http://app.flowhub.io/#runtime/endpoint?protocol%3Dwebsocket%26address%3Dws%3A%2F%2F192.168.43.64%3A3569%26id%3D173bb627-f1df-48cf-80da-d2b72546c08c%26secret%3Dtupiqiyoma
> **Component interaction/ListenChange not available with base C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\my-app**

Can someone please help me with this issue?
(Sorry I can post images related to it because I am a new user)

Answer (score 0):

noflo-interaction components are only available for browser environment. So they're not visible to noflo-nodejs.